# Intuition Behind Balanced Sets

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, functional-analysis

Suppose $B \subset X$ where $X$ is a vector space. $B$ is called balanced if $\alpha B \subset B$ for every $\alpha \in \Phi$ with $|\alpha| \leq 1$. Note that $\Phi = \textbf{R}$ or $\Phi = \textbf{C}$. What is the intuition behind balanced sets? Why do we define them? Is it "good" for a vector space to have more balanced sets? Why do we require $| \alpha| \leq 1$?

Comment: Think about this: Look at $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{C}$), what is the smallest balanced set containing $A=\{(1,1)\}$, $B=\{(1,1),(0,1)\}$, $C=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}$?

Comment: The unit circle?

Comment: Do you adopt $|\alpha|\le 1$ (KennyTM edited the text)? Think it over again (using pen+paper), $\alpha$ is real over $\mathbb{R}$ and complex over $\mathbb{C}$. In one occasion you WILL get the unit disc (usually unit circle is the boundary of the unit disc)!

Comment: I think the set is said to be balance if the sum of all its members is zero. Now I am tring to define balance equation which will be published in my article in near future. I have claimed that the general polynomial equation of degree 5 can be solvable by radical if it is balance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Added in response to the comments below:] Despite what is written below,
*balanced* needn't imply convex; it simply doesn't follow from the definition.  So one should take the following discussion as rather an explanation about *convex* balanced sets, for whatever that is worth.

[Original answer follows:]

*Balanced* means that the set is symmetric around the origin (i.e. invariant under $v \mapsto -v$) and is convex.  These are nice properties, generalizing some useful features of balls around the origin in $\mathbb R^n$.  (Incidentally, if you didn't have the condition $|\alpha| = 1$, then any balanced subset with non-empty interior (in $\mathbb R^n$ say) would be all of $\mathbb R^n$, so that wouldn't be such an interesting condition.)

Also, any vector space will have plenty of such sets; you can form them just by taking the convex hull of a collection of points invariant under $v \mapsto -v$.  What is more relevant in functional analysis is whether the origin of a topological vector space contains a *basis* of balaced neighbourhoods.  The topological vector space is then called *locally convex* and this has important consequences for the space (especially for
its duality theory).

Note that balls around the origin in a normed space are automatically balanced, so normed spaces are locally convex; so again, in the topological setting, one sees that this is a way of capturing some the geometric aspects
of normed vector spaces, without insisting on the existence of a norm.
(So, while normed spaces are not closed under certain operations, such as
forming infinite direct sums, locally convex spaces are --- any direct sum
(just to take one example) of a collection of locally convex spaces has 
a natural locally convex topology of its own.)

Comment: Is a balanced set necessary convex? If over a real vector space, I thought it suffices that the set is star-shaped w.r.t. 0.

Comment: I also don't see why if you didn't have $\lvert\alpha\rvert \le 1$, a balanced subset couldn't be an infinite star-shaped region, like a double cone, and not all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Willie, @Rahul: Dear Willie and Rahul, Thanks a lot, you are both correct; I was thinking too much about the locally convex set-up, rather than what was literally under discussion.  I have added a big caveat at the start of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In *Complex analysis in locally convex spaces* by Seán Dineen, it states that:

> Balanced open sets arise as the natural domain of convergence of Taylor series expansion at the origin of *holomorphic functions.*

Comment: @Chandru1: If you are going to copy from a google books search, you might want to try cut-n-paste instead, and thus avoid introducing incorrect punctuation.

Comment: @Arturo: The thing is i couldn't do that,

Comment: @Arturo: Are u asking abt the link!

Comment: @Chandru: No, I'm not asking anything. I'm pointing out that you are trying (or claiming) to quote verbatim from a book, but you introduced incorrect punctuation (a comma after "arise"; capital letter in "Holomorphic"; a missing period at the end of the sentence). If you are going to quote, then quote accurately. If you cannot quote accurately when copying, then use cut-n-paste so you don't introduce errors that will then be attributed to the original author.

Comment: @Arturo: See i couldn't do that while visiting that page. Thats why i didn't do it. I have clearly mentioned that it is from that book

Comment: @Chandru1: You couldn't do *what*? You couldn't cut and paste? Or are you physically unable to quote without introducing errors? *Learn to quote accurately*, or stop trying to quote other people. "Quoting accurately" is not about giving appropriate citations, it's about *quoting*: repeating. If you are claiming to quote, then your quote should be *exactly* what the other person wrote/said, and any changes need to be explicitly marked (in sundry typographical ways). If you are merely paraphrasing, then don't present it as a quote.

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, i couldn't cut and paste as i opened google books.

Comment: @Chandru1: If you look up quickly, you might catch a glimpse of my point flying by.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the above answer made by (now) @anonymous, the "natural domains of convergence of Taylor series" are logarithmically-convex complete Reinhardt domains. Two questions arise:

Q1. What do these words mean?

Q2. What does natural domain of convergence mean?

To answer these questions, let us first note by "domain", we mean a connected open set in $\mathbb{C}^n$. I do not want to touch on anything outside of domains in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

A domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is said to be a *Reinhardt domain centred at $w \in \Omega$* if, for any point $z = (z_1, ..., z_n) \in \Omega$, the rotations $(w_1 + z_1 e^{i\vartheta_1}, ..., w_n + z_n e^{i\vartheta_n})$ lie in $\Omega$ also, where $\vartheta_j \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $j \in \{ 1, ..., n \}$. If $w = (w_1, ..., _n)$ is the origin in $\mathbb{C}^n$, I believe this is the definition of *balanced*.

A Reinhardt domain (centred at $w \in \mathbb{C}^n$) $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is said to be *complete* if for any point $\zeta \in \Omega$, the polydisk $$\Delta(w, \zeta - w) := \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n : \left| z_j - w_j \right| \leq \left| \zeta_j - w_j \right|, 1 \leq j \leq n \right \}$$ is contained in $\Omega$. In other words, a Reinhardt domain is complete if it can be "filled up by polydisks".

To describe logarithmic convexity, let us denote by $\mathcal{D}$ the complement of all coordinate hyperplanes in $\mathbb{C}^n$, i.e., $$\mathcal{D} = \{ z= (z_1, ..., z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n : z_j \neq 0, \ \forall \ 1 \leq j \leq n \}.$$ Then a set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is *logarithmically-convex* if $$\lambda(\Omega \cap \mathcal{D}) = \left \{ \zeta = (\zeta_1, ..., \zeta_n) : \zeta_j = \log | z_j |, \ 1 \leq j \leq n \right \}$$ is a convex set.

One may show without too much difficulty that the domain of convergence of a power series is a complete Reinhardt domain. If one asks the converse question, however, i.e., whether, given a complete Reinhardt domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$, does there exist a power series whose domain of convergence is exactly $\Omega$, the answer is negative. If $\Omega$ is further assumed to be logarithmically-convex however, then it will be true that we can find a power series with $\Omega$ as the domain of convergence.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that *complete* in the sense I have just described, corresponds to *absorbent* in functional analysis?

Hope this helps.